# git: Best way to determine unmerged branches in a script

Tags: git, merge, git-branch, git-plumbing

At an interactive prompt, I can use the `git branch -r --no-merged` command to determine remote branches that haven't been merged yet. However, `git branch` is a porcelain command and therefore is not suitable for use in a script.

Is there any good plumbing command I can use to determine the same branches returned by the `--no-merged` option?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589862/git-find-all-unmerged-commits-in-master-grouped-by-the-branches-they-were-create) has some suggestions around parsing this information. Maybe you can find something there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the command `git merge-base` supports an `--is-ancestor` argument to check if a commit is contained in the history of another. Using this, I can find unmerged remote refs like this (in ksh):

```
function showUnmerged {
    typeset -a unmergedRefs=()

    git for-each-ref --format='%(objectname) %(refname)' refs/remotes | \
    while read -r hash ref; do
        git merge-base --is-ancestor "$hash" "$1" || unmergedRefs+=("$ref")
    done

    echo "${unmergedRefs[@]}"
}

showUnmerged HEAD
```

This doesn't seem to be particularly efficient, but it does work and as far as I know, both `for-each-ref` and `merge-base` are plumbing commands